# Помогите привязать checkbox к кнопке

Tags: javascript, php, css

Помогите пожалуйста привязать checkbox к кнопке. Есть кнопка "Добавить в корзину". Как к ней привязать checkbox с текстом "Ознакомлен и согласен с политикой конфиденциальности"? Чтобы не выбрав checkbox, нельзя было добавить в корзину. Я сам уже все перепробовал... У меня не работает( Спасибо!

```php
<?php
do_action('wpd_cart_box', $this->editor->wpd_product);
?>
<button id="add-to-cart-btn" class="wpc-btn-effect" data-id="<?php echo $this->editor->item_id ?>"><?php echo $add_to_cart_label; ?></button>
```

Comment: Ну как идея, для начала делаете кнопку саму не активной, тоесть добавляя ей атрибут disabled. Тогда, когда пользователь нажал на галочку проверям, если checked то тогода с кнопки убираем disabled, если !checked тогда кнопке добавляем атрибут disabled. Могу навести пример или же вам не понятна сама логика происходящего?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, вы имели ввиду, что-то вроде:

```js
let inp = document.querySelector('.inp'); //находим чекбокс
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn'); //находим кнопку
let form = document.querySelector('.form')  //находим форму

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault(); //блокируем действие по умолчанию
})

inp.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  if (event.target.checked) { //если чекбокс эктив
    btn.disabled = false; //значит убираем дисэйблэд с кнопки
  } else {
    btn.disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="" class = 'form'>

    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class = 'inp'>
    Ознакомлен и согласен с политикой конфиденциальности</label>
  <button class = 'btn' type = 'submit' disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: можно чуть короче  btn.disabled = !event.target.checked

Answer (score 0):

Установите плагин https://wordpress.org/plugins/saphali-woocommerce-lite/
С помощью него можно будет и новое поле добавить и порядок изменить и многое другое.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]